# Why I get my collecion of users and an extra object when get request with Node Express and Backbone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, express

This code gets stuff from database and sends it back to backbone front end. When I console log the items I get nice array with my desired object inside.

Mongo and Node with express:

```
app.get('/fighterslist', function(req, res) {
    db.collection('userlist', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
            console.log(items) // nice
            res.send(items);
        });
    });
});
```

Then Backbone collects the data:

```
FightersListModel = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    urlRoot: '/fighterslist',

    initialize: function(){
        var that = this;
        this.fetch({
            success: function (fightersList) {

            console.log(fightersList); //unexpected results

            that.set("fightersList", fightersList.toJSON());
            }
        });
    },
});
```

The log from the code above shows an object containing all the rows from the collection so its very nice. Problem is it has an extra object at the end and it also contains an object containing all the rows from the collection.

So if I .toJSON() it, it would have and extra empty object at the end. Here's the console log console.log(fightersList.toJSON()):

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, fightersList: Object}
    0: Object
    1: Object
    2: Object
    3: Object
    4: Object
    fightersList: Object
        __proto__: Object
        __defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
        __defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }
        __lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }
        __lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }
        arguments: null
        caller: null
        length: 1
        name: "__lookupSetter__"
        __proto__: function Empty() {}
        <function scope>
        constructor: function Object() { [native code] }
        hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
        isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }
        propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }
        toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
        toString: function toString() { [native code] }
        valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
        get __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
        set __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
__proto__: Object
```

Why do I get this extra object?

Comment: because you put it there with `that.set("fightersList", fightersList.toJSON());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you're mixing collections and models. The mongo code is returning a collection (array) while `FightersListModel` is a `Backbone.Model` object. You probably meant something like this:

```
var FightersListModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: '/fighterslist'
});
var FightersListCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: FightersListModel
});

var fightersListCollection = new FightersListCollection();
fightersListCollection.fetch();
```

**please note I could not test the above code, it's a rough guess of what might work*

According to the docs [Backbone.Collection.fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) automatically sets the contents for you. Simply calling fetch is all you need to do.

You have the extra object in the log because, after fetching the data you manually set the `fighterList` property to `fightersList.toJSON()`. This is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I don't think the extra object is from that.set("fightersList", fightersList.toJSON());. I could log fighterslist before doing toJSON  and it had that extra object at the end. I've managed to get right results using Backbone.Collection instead of Model.

Comment: @dufia Did you try removing that line to test? Logging objects to the console is a little wacky, and it will reflect any changes you make to the object after you log it up until I think you expand the object in the console.

Comment: @david I've tried before and couldn't make it work as you expect it to. I might done something wrong. I've used Collection to solve main problem and now its fine for me, I'm moving on. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the right results doing it like that:

```
var FightersList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/fighterslist',

    model: FighterModel,

    initialize: function(){
        this.fetch();
    }
});
```

So the collections contains models corresponding with data from db. I still don't understand that extra object from my question thought.